# Eigenvalues and Eigenfrequencies

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to understand the concept of eigenfrequencies.

For instance, in the following exercise one is asked to find the eigenvalues and the eigenfrequencies of the following matrix:

\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}

By the definition of eigenvalues, it is quite simple to see that these are the diagonal elements.

However, what exactly is the *eigenfrequencies*? I barely find any information on this concept - is it equal to the determinant of the matrix?

Comment: In what context did you encounter this question? Please provide more details. Something tells me this comes from differential equations...

Comment: It is part of "mathematical methods for physics", the exercises before are the derivation of equilibrium states of moving objects, e.g. fixed by a feather. Unfortunately, I don't have any further information about the "eigenfrequencies"

Comment: You need to see how many times $x-\lambda$ divides the characteristic polynomial. In this case it la clear it is only once.